# Check if Bootstrap Datepicker script has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am receiving the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

When I try to set up the datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

How can I determine if the datepicker has loaded or not?

**To be clear, I'm not using jQuery UI**

Comment: You are missing jquery UI library.

Comment: @Tomanow Sorry for the confusion, I'm not using jQuery UI, I'm using bootstrap datepicker - http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can check to see if the datepicker script has loaded using:

```
if ($.fn.datepicker) {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can conditionally invoke the `.datepicker()` method if the script has loaded:

```
if ($.fn.datepicker) {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kq6fbbw4/)

In doing so, the error won't be thrown if the script hasn't loaded.

---

You can also use:

```
if (typeof $().datepicker === 'function') {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/45sjakf1/)

Comment: Brilliant! THanks. I wasn't sure if this would be possible.

Comment: no need for a var, `if($.fn.datepicker){ ... }` works as well

Answer (score -1):

This stopped me loading bootstrap-datepicker more than once throughout modals..

```
$.isFunction(Date.today) || $('body').append('<script src="assets/bootstrap-daterangepicker/date.js"><\/script><script src="assets/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"><\/script>');
```